# Can't run JUnit in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I create simple Java Application project with `src` and `test` folders. `src` folder consists of the class which I test and `test` folder consists of the class where I describe test. When I start testing, using JUnit 4 I get: **Could not find the main class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.  Program will exit.** error. All JAR files are presented in my project.

What did I miss in my project?

Comment: Have you added the JUnit jar to the build path?

Comment: The answer for your question is in my post's last sentence

Comment: Since this class is internal to eclipse there seems to be a problem with eclipse. I would first try restarting eclipse, the computer and then try re-installing eclipse.

Comment: Ho do you "start testing"? Do you use the "Run as JUnit" functionality?

Comment: @ShiDoiSi Could you explain what do you mean more concretely?

Comment: You have your Java project in Eclipse. How do you go about running the unit-tests? Do you use the context menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a class that is part of the Eclipse plugin, it sounds like you have a corrupted installation of Eclipse. Try with a fresh installation.

Comment: I reinstalled fresh eclipse version as you suggest, but there is no change, I also now have conflicts between versions of my JRE libraries, but I fix this problem. I also have Android SDK integrated in my Eclipse and firstly when I launched the test, system asked me for what kind of JUnit I would like to use, I chose Eclipse

Comment: After long investigation I reinstalled my jdk to the newest version and also reinstalled eclipse, all what I changed is: I didn't use uppercase in folder's name and didn't use spaces in directory's name, because I read that sometimes eclipse has problems with spaces in names. Now everything is fine, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Far shot: is the `test`-folder containing the `.java`-files for your tests also declared as a source-folder in the project's Build Path settings?

Comment: Yes, it is also source folder.

Answer (score 0):

All JUnit tests should be written as follows:

```
@Test    //This is very very important

public void testAbc()
{
//Test Abc() here....
}
```